# Google Cloud Deploy OCR Extract Error - build failed with status:failure and message: missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have been trying to utilize Gcloud Optical Character Recognition (OCR) to read text from images. My end goal is be able to upload an image to my image bucket on Gcloud and then have the Google OCR software extract, translate and save the text of the image. However, when I tried to deploy the OCR extract, translate or save functions they all give me the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: missing main.py and GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE not specified. Either create the function in main.py or specify GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SOURCE to point to the file that contains the function; Error ID: 5c04ec9c

I used the sample code google provided below with minor updates.

```
# [START functions_cloudevent_ocr]
import base64
import json
import os

from cloudevents.http import CloudEvent

import functions_framework

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
from google.cloud import vision


vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
translate_client = translate.Client()
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
storage_client = storage.Client()

project_id = os.environ.get("just-vent-407916")
# [END functions_cloudevent_ocr]


# [START functions_ocr_process]
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def process_image(cloud_event: CloudEvent) -> None:
    """Cloud Function triggered by Cloud Storage when a file is changed.

    Gets the names of the newly created object and its bucket then calls
    detect_text to find text in that image.

    detect_text finishes by sending PubSub messages requesting another service
    then complete processing those texts by translating them and saving the
    translations.
    """

    # Check that the received event is of the expected type, return error if not
    expected_type = "google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized"
    received_type = cloud_event["type"]
    if received_type != expected_type:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected {expected_type} but received {received_type}")

    # Extract the bucket and file names of the uploaded image for processing
    data = cloud_event.data
    bucket = data["bucket"]
    filename = data["name"]

    # Process the information in the new image
    detect_text(bucket, filename)

    print(f"File {filename} processed.")


# [END functions_ocr_process]


# [START functions_ocr_detect]
def detect_text(bucket: str, filename: str) -> None:
    """Extract the text from an image uploaded to Cloud Storage, then
    publish messages requesting subscribing services translate the text
    to each target language and save the result.

    Args:
        bucket: name of GCS bucket in which the file is stored.
        filename: name of the file to be read.
    """

    print(f"Looking for text in image {filename}")

    # Use the Vision API to extract text from the image
    image = vision.Image(
        source=vision.ImageSource(gcs_image_uri=f"gs://{bucket}/{filename}")
    )
    text_detection_response = vision_client.text_detection(image=image)
    annotations = text_detection_response.text_annotations

    if annotations:
        text = annotations[0].description
    else:
        text = ""
    print(f"Extracted text {text} from image ({len(text)} chars).")

    detect_language_response = translate_client.detect_language(text)
    src_lang = detect_language_response["language"]
    print(f"Detected language {src_lang} for text {text}.")

    # Submit a message to the bus for each target language
    futures = []  # Asynchronous publish request statuses

    to_langs = os.environ.get("TO_LANG", "").split(",")
    for target_lang in to_langs:
        topic_name = os.environ.get("TRANSLATE_TOPIC")
        if src_lang == target_lang or src_lang == "und":
            topic_name = os.environ.get("RESULT_TOPIC")

        message = {
            "text": text,
            "filename": filename,
            "lang": target_lang,
            "src_lang": src_lang,
        }

        message_data = json.dumps(message).encode("utf-8")
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=message_data)
        futures.append(future)

    # Wait for each publish request to be completed before exiting
    for future in futures:
        future.result()


# [END functions_ocr_detect]


# [START functions_ocr_translate]
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def translate_text(cloud_event: CloudEvent) -> None:
    """Cloud Function triggered by PubSub when a message is received from
    a subscription.

    Translates the text in the message from the specified source language
    to the requested target language, then sends a message requesting another
    service save the result.
    """

    # Check that the received event is of the expected type, return error if not
    expected_type = "google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished"
    received_type = cloud_event["type"]
    if received_type != expected_type:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected {expected_type} but received {received_type}")

    # Extract the message body, expected to be a JSON representation of a
    # dictionary, and extract the fields from that dictionary.
    data = cloud_event.data["message"]["data"]
    try:
        message_data = base64.b64decode(data)
        message = json.loads(message_data)

        text = message["text"]
        filename = message["filename"]
        target_lang = message["lang"]
        src_lang = message["src_lang"]
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Missing or malformed PubSub message {data}: {e}.")

    # Translate the text and publish a message with the translation
    print(f"Translating text into {target_lang}.")

    translated_text = translate_client.translate(
        text, target_language=target_lang, source_language=src_lang
    )

    topic_name = os.environ["RESULT_TOPIC"]
    message = {
        "text": translated_text["translatedText"],
        "filename": filename,
        "lang": target_lang,
    }
    message_data = json.dumps(message).encode("utf-8")
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=message_data)
    future.result()  # Wait for operation to complete


# [END functions_ocr_translate]


# [START functions_ocr_save]
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def save_result(cloud_event: CloudEvent) -> None:
    """Cloud Function triggered by PubSub when a message is received from
    a subscription.

    Saves translated text to a Cloud Storage object as requested.
    """
    # Check that the received event is of the expected type, return error if not
    expected_type = "google.cloud.pubsub.topic.v1.messagePublished"
    received_type = cloud_event["type"]
    if received_type != expected_type:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected {expected_type} but received {received_type}")

    # Extract the message body, expected to be a JSON representation of a
    # dictionary, and extract the fields from that dictionary.
    data = cloud_event.data["message"]["data"]
    try:
        message_data = base64.b64decode(data)
        message = json.loads(message_data)

        text = message["text"]
        filename = message["filename"]
        lang = message["lang"]
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Missing or malformed PubSub message {data}: {e}.")

    print(f"Received request to save file {filename}.")

    # Save the translation in RESULT_BUCKET
    bucket_name = os.environ["RESULT_BUCKET"]
    result_filename = f"{filename}_{lang}.txt"
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(result_filename)

    print(f"Saving result to {result_filename} in bucket {bucket_name}.")

    blob.upload_from_string(text)

    print("File saved.")


# [END functions_ocr_save]
```

```
When I try to deploy the following in a cloud shell terminal for my project 

gcloud functions deploy ocr-extract \
--gen2 \
--runtime=python312 \
--region=northamerica-northeast2 \
--source=. \
--entry-point=process_image \
--trigger-bucket trigger_bucket \
--set-env-vars "^:^GCP_PROJECT=just-vent-407916:TRANSLATE_TOPIC=translatetopic:RESULT_TOPIC=resulttopic:TO_LANG=es,en,fr,ja"
```

I receive the error above. These instructions are available in https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploy?cloudshell=true

I have been able to upload an image successfully through the Gcloud shell terminal.

I have the extract, save and translate folder downloaded in the same folder with the python script.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Okay, thanks I did not know, it's my first post here. I have edited it. Are you able to help with the question?

Comment: The error message is telling you what to do.  Have you tried either of the choices?  If you tried its recommendations at they didn't work, you should be clear about that in your question.

Comment: Yes, I have tried either of the choices. Tried to deploy from gcloud and console but both don't work. Main.py does exist as well.